# LinuxのRにsemPlotパッケージがインストールできません。

Tags: linux, r

Linux上のRクライアントに因子分析のパスを表示するsemPlotパッケージをインストールしようとしているのですが、エラーとなりうまくできません。どなたかLinux上のRでsemPlotパッケージのインストールに成功した方はいらっしゃいますでしょうか。
Windows上のRではRcmdrが勝手にインストールしてくれるのですが、Linux版だとうまくいきません。

Rのバージョン

```
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31) -- "Pumpkin Helmet"
Copyright (C) 2014 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
```

OSバージョン

```
CentOS release 6.6 (Final)
```

インストールしようとすると長い時間がかかって最終的にエラーとなります。

```
install.packages("semPlot")

ダウンロードされたパッケージは、以下にあります
‘/tmp/RtmpiyTQxe/downloaded_packages’
'.Library' 中のパッケージの HTML 索引を更新します
Making 'packages.html' ... 完了
警告メッセージ:
1: In install.packages("semPlot") :
パッケージ ‘rtiff’ のインストールは、ゼロでない終了値をもちました
2: In install.packages("semPlot") :
パッケージ ‘sendplot’ のインストールは、ゼロでない終了値をもちました
3: In install.packages("semPlot") :
パッケージ ‘qgraph’ のインストールは、ゼロでない終了値をもちました
4: In install.packages("semPlot") :
パッケージ ‘semPlot’ のインストールは、ゼロでない終了値をもちました
```

このようにsemPlotをインストールする前段階のrtiffのインストールができません。
ですので、Linux上のRでrtiffのインストールができればもしかするとsemPlotもインストールできるのかもと思っているのですがいずれにせよrtiffもsemPlotもインストールに成功していません。

Comment: ここで教えていただいた情報をもとに何台かのSentOS6サーバにsemPlotモジュールをインストールしましたが、事前に下記４モジュールをyumでインストールしておくとsemPlotのインストール成功するということがわかりました。

libtiff-devel  
libxml2-devel  
libjpeg-devel  
libpng-devel

Answer (score 2):

`CentOS`じゃなくて恐縮ですが、`Arch`では`rtiff`の導入には

- `tcl`(libtck.8.6.so)
- `tk`(libtk.8.6.so)
- `libtiff`(`rtiff`が依存しているとCRANに記述があります)

をインストールしておく必要がありました。

---

**追記**
Vagrantを利用して`CentOS6.6(64bit)`の仮想環境を作って試してみました。適当に探したイメージファイルを使用しています。

```
$ mkdir centos66 && cd $_
$ vagrant init hnakamur/centos6.6-x64
$ vagrant up && vagrant ssh
```

`CentOS6.6`にログインしました。

```
$ sudo su    
# rpm -ihv http://ftp.riken.jp/Linux/fedora/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
# yum -y install R
```

して`R`を導入し、実行します。

```
> install.packages("rtiff")
(中略)
Installing *source* package ‘rtiff' ... .
** package ‘rtiff' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checkedc
checking for gcc... gcc 
checking whether the C compiler works... yes 
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes 
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes 
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for TIFFOpen in -ltiff... no
Try static libs needed on OS X
checking for TIFFOpen in -ltiff... no
Error: Could not find libtiff.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rtiff‘
(略)
```

`libtiff`が無いと言われますので、一旦`R`を終了し、`libtiff`のインストールをします。

```
yum -y install libtiff-devel
```

その後、再度`install.packages("rtiff")`を実行すると無事インストールが完了しました。

尚、`semPlot`はかなり多数のパッケージに依存しているようです。都度エラーが発生するかと思いますが、その度にエラーメッセージを読んで、1つずつ必要なライブラリをインストールしていくと良いでしょう。(`CRAN`を見てあらかじめ依存ライブラリをリストアップするという方法もあります。)

Comment: おそらく何か依存モジュールが足りないのがエラーの原因ではと
CentOS6では事前に
yum install libxml2-devel
yum install libjpeg-devel
yum install libpng-devel
をインストールしてからやってみたのですが、未だにrtiffおよびsemPlotのインストールに成功していません。
しかしながら別のディストリビューションとはいえ同じLinuxでの成功例があるということで希望が持てました。情報ありがとうございました。

Comment: 実際にCentOS6で試してみた結果を追記します。

Comment: さっそく２台のサーバでlibtiff-develをインストールしてからsemPlotパッケージをインストールしてみました。
２台ともsemPlotパッケージのインストールに成功しました
libtiffについては必要だろうと思っていましたが、最初からインストール済みでした。libtiff-develが必要だったのですね。気が付きませんでした。
大変ありがとうございました。またとても勉強になりました。

Answer (score 1):

CentOS 6.6だと同じエラーが出ていましたが、以下のコマンドを叩いてrtiffをインストールしたらsemPlotパッケージがインストール出来ました。

```
sudo yum install libtiff-devel
```

Comment: ありがとうございました。２台のサーバでlibtiff-develをインストールしてからsemPlotパッケージをインストール後、２台ともsemPlotパッケージのインストールに成功しました。libtiffではなく、libtiff-develが必要だったのですね。 情報ありがとうございました。

Comment: @DaisukeMatsumoto 問題が解決して何よりです。